# Deriving projection matrix $QQ^Tb=\hat b$ from normal equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, projection-matrices, gram-schmidt

Suppose normal equation $A^TA\hat x=A^Tb$, with $A$ has linearly dependent columns. Is it possible to directly derive from this normal equation that $QQ^Tb=\hat b$, with $A=QR$? Or we can only prove it from the geometric point of view?

Comment: Are you sure it is $QQ^\intercal b = \hat b$? If I remember correctly, $A^\intercal A = R^\intercal R,$ isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define $\hat{b}$. If you define $\hat{b}$ as the projection of $b$ onto the column space of $A$ then clearly the geometric argument is the way to go. If you define $\hat{b}$ as the "$b$" that the least-square system is really solving for (that is $\hat{b} = A\hat{x}$) then you can derive it algebraically.

Suppose $A = QR$ where $A$ is $m\times n$, $Q$ is an $m \times n$  orthogonal matrix and $R$ is $n \times n$, with $m > n$. Let $\hat{x}$ be the solution to the normal equation $A^TAx = A^Tb$. Define $\hat{b} = A\hat{x}$.

Then

$$ \begin{align*} A^TA\hat{x}& = A^Tb \\
(QR)^T(QR)\hat{x} & = (QR)^Tb \\
R^TR\hat{x} & = R^TQ^Tb \\ 
R\hat{x}& = Q^Tb \\
QR\hat{x} & = QQ^Tb \\
\hat{b} & = QQ^Tb 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Isn't $R^T$ non invertible if A has linearly dependent column?

Comment: You can modify things in that case. If $k$ is the rank of $A$ then let $A = QR$ where $Q$ is $m \times k$ and $R$ is a $k \times n$ trapezoidal matrix. $R$ will have full row rank and so $R^T$ will have full column rank / linearly independent columns. Therefore $R^Tx = R^Ty \rightarrow x = y$